# What does it mean ?

Tags: idioms

I am learning English, but I am not familiar with idioms. Could somebody explain me in plain English what does it mean "I will need to come back to you on this request."

Comment: You probably should be in the English Language Learners exchange.

Comment: In this context, *to **come/get back** to someone* is an idiomatic expression that means *to contact them again* (after you've done something or found some relevant information elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple translation is "I don't have an answer right now and I will let you know as soon as I do have an answer."